# Controllability of a pair of matrices

Tags: matrices, control-theory, matrix-rank, linear-control

If the pair $(A,B)$ is controllable, then is the pair $(A^{2},(A+I)B)$ controllable?

The question becomes more interesting if there exists $(A,B)$ is uncontrollable, but the pair $(A^{2},(A+I)B)$ controllable.

Comment: If A = -I, then we always have (A+I)*B = 0. Therefore, the system is not controllable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

What you are asking is, if the following implication holds:
$$ (\forall A,B) \: (\text{rk}(P(A,B)) = n) \rightarrow (\text{rk}(P(A^2, (A+I)B)) = n), $$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, B\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $P$ the controllability matrix $P(A,B) = (B, AB, ..., A^{n-1}B)$.

Take $n=1$ and $b \neq 0$:
$$
\begin{align}
P(A,B) & = P(a,b) = b, \\
P(A^2, (A+I)B) & = P(a^2, (a+1)b) = (a+1)b.
\end{align}
$$
If, e.g., $a = -1$ we have that 
$$\text{rk}(P(A^2, (A+I)B) = \text{rk}((-1+1)b) = 0 \neq 1 = \text{rk}(P(A,B)).$$

Hence, 
$$ (\exists A,B) \: (\text{rk}(P(A,B)) = n) \wedge (\text{rk}(P(A^2, (A+I)B)) \neq n) $$
which is the negation of the above given implication.